# Authentication Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpmodule

I have one project in asp.net using httpModules. But i got one exception while debugging,
the error shows like this:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.

I don't know whats the problem in my code, i refereed many sites, but there is no correct solution at there.  please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to enable anonymous access on IIS